# Retrieve ID of deleted Database row in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, database

I have a FormView through which I set up the default `new`, `update` and `delete` commands for communicating with an SQL Server database.

When the `CREATE` command is executed the data is added to the database and some images are uploaded to a server and linked to the database.

#### Problem

When I press the Visual Studio's default FormView DELETE command I obviously only delete the selected row in the database and not the images on the server.

I marked the uploaded images with `images ID + "name"` , so I could delete them if I could only retrieve the ID of the row being deleted by the DELETE command.

How do I do retrieve the ID of the deleted row in C#?

Comment: have you tired getting the ID before you execute the delete command? Using, for example, a simple select?

Comment: webforms, sorry I fogot to say that, anyway I got the anwser from Coding Gorilla..
thanks anyway for the quick anwsers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the *best* solution would be to rework the design of your database a little bit and use a foreign key on your images.  You could then set the images to be deleted by the database when the primary key (your data table) is deleted using a cascade.

Alternatively, assuming you cannot change your database schema, you can use the [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcommand.aspx) event from the FormView.  This will let you intercept the commands as they're being processed; you can also handle the ItemDeleting or ItemDeleted events.

Comment: As I understand, the images aren't in the database

Comment: yes the images aren't in the database, i'm going to try the handleing ItemCommand event... from the example i think that'll work..
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the SqlDataSource's `Deleting` event.

Answer (score 0):

hm...
i didn't know FormView.SelectedValue gets the id of the selected value from the formview, but as I tested now.. apparently it does...